# Analysing a microscope image

Tags: cell-biology

After a session of practical work in cellular biology, I stumbled across this image of human cheek cells. As seen on the sample below several particles envelop one of the cells. What are they?
[image]

The stain: is methylene Blue.

The image was taken by an optical microscope at 40X.

The method of extraction is the following:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

These could be:

- Small particles of methylene blue crystallizing on the cell's surface
- Dirt from the mouth
- Dirt from the swab
- Bacteria

My best guess is bacteria, since that explains why they are focusing on one particular cell. But one needs more of these occurences to be sure.

Comment: bacteria at 40X magnification ?

Comment: Yes bacteria at [40x magnification](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Light-Microscopic-photograph-at-40X-magnification-showing-Gram-Positive-nature-of_fig1_26618929). Clumps of bacteria are even seen in 10x; not at single cell resolution, but well enough to see if cell cultures are contaminated. Hell, you can even see mitochondria in 5x if you stain them.